# iTextSharp can't read some PDF files

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a problem to read and display content of some PDFs into `RichTextBox`.
I use the following code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\SomePdf.pdf";
string str = string.Empty;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its);

    s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
    str = str + s;
    rtbVsebina.Text = str;
}

reader.Close();
```

Some PDFs can be read and displayed into `RichTextBox` and some they can not be. For those that can not be read I only get empty `RichTextBox` but with some added lines as I would press Key 'Enter' on the keyboard a couple of times.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: What *does* happen? any errors? nothing displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing page content with page annotations.

Page content is part of the content stream of a page. It's referred to in the `/Contents` entry of the page dictionary and (optionally) in external objects (aka `XObjects`). With the code snippet you have copy/pasted in your question, you are extracting this content.

A rich text box is one of the many types of annotations. Annotations are **not** part of the content stream of a page. They are referred to from the `/Annots` entry of the page dictionary. If you want to get the contents of an annotation, you need to ask the page for its annotations instead of parsing the content of the page. See for instance [Reading PDF Annotations with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474210/reading-pdf-annotations-with-itext).

In answer to your question "What am I doing wrong": you were looking at the wrong place.